# Linux, Fedora. Auto-install all software to a new machine from RPM list?

Tags: linux, rpm, list

What is the best way to produce an rpm list on one machine, and then use it to auto-install all that software onto a new machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same version of fedora ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming same linux version:

on old: `rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}\n" > list.txt`

on new: `dnf install $(cat list.txt)`

Also assuming your repo lists are all the same and all represented on the new machine.

Sometimes packages change names, or some have specific versions in the actual name, so if this is between fedora versions it's less likely to work. But it'll get you most of the way there most likely. For a new system on the same version it should work fine.